# Improve performance on Listview with image

Tags: wpf

I am working on a WPF application with .NET 4.5.

I request image list from Google picasa API and bind the images to a ListView.

Currently, I get the thumbnails in low resolution quality (200px x 200px) and bind to the item template.

If the number of images is under 500, it is fine on memory usage and the scroll bar is still smooth.
However, if album contains more than 1000 images, the application will start lagging on scrolling and the memory usage is increased significantly.

So any suggestion on how to improve the performance?

How do the image viewers such as ACDSEE,Xnview etc. achieve that?

I am considering paging (e.g. 500 images per page), but it seems not quite user-friendly.

Below is piece of the Xaml:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="PhotoDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Classes:AlbumClass}">
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#B7B7B7" BorderThickness="1" Width="160" Height="160">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ThumbUrlLarge}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="150">
                        </Image>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="PhotoItemsPanelTemplate">
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ListPhoto}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                <ListBox Name="ListPhoto" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                         Height="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualHeight}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         SelectionMode="Extended"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PhotoDataTemplate}" 
                         ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource PhotoItemsPanelTemplate}">
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: first step : don't [disable UI Virtualization by setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: next step : implement some kind of [Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)  to your ListBox's ItemsSource data.

Comment: Just set VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" or even leave that away since ListView supports virtualizing by design. No need for Data Virtualization here.

Comment: @devhedgehog why Data Virtualization not needed here?

Comment: It would cause laggy scrolling in this case.

Comment: Thanks you everyone, i still trying any possible fix.

Comment: @devhedgehog if you make your image binding async it should work smoothly.

Comment: @Gusdor Data Virtualization has nothing to do with Async Flag in Binding. Binding will be triggered after new data got fetched so there is no matter if async or not in this case. However async lazy loading the data would at least stop the UI from freezing but still scrolling wouldn't look smooth. So my suggest load all data from google and then let the ListView do the UI Virtualization. Shiba preload the data and set IsVirtualizing to True and you should do fine. :)

Comment: @devhedgehog the latency is derived from creating and displaying the image elements. The data is there already. Binding the image in async will stop the binding (and subsequent display) from blocking the UI thread on creation of a new item. Instead, it is re-dispatched for later. Try it and see.

Comment: @Gusdor That is very true but I do not think the OP has issues with downloading images while scrolling/loading the control. OP downloaded data already.